# Is there an open source library JS for keyboard binding in the browser?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, open-source, keyboard, cross-browser

I am looking to create a JavaScript app that relies heavily on keyboard shortcuts, is here a open-source library that answers those needs with cross-browser support and an easy Api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[KeyMaster](https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster)

> A simple micro-library for defining and dispatching keyboard
>   shortcuts. It has no dependencies.

```
// define short of 'a'
key('a', function(){ alert('you pressed a!') });

// returning false stops the event and prevents default browser events
key('ctrl+r', function(){ alert('stopped reload!'); return false });

// multiple shortcuts that do the same thing
key('⌘+r, ctrl+r', function(){ });
```

Answer (score 4):

I recently wrote a library called mousetrap.  Check it out at http://craig.is/killing/mice.

It is similar to keymaster, but also supports key sequences, international keyboard layouts, binding directly to special characters, specifying which event to listen for, etc.

It has no dependencies as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [jquery.hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) and [KeyboardJS](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/KeyboardJS/).